# Zero impressions to a lot of pages while I can see still see them in Google? Huge drop

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, search-results

In Google Search Console I can see hundreds of search queries dropping impressions from e.g. 800 to literally 0 (!), while I can still see them on Google when I search for them. I know that Google did a massive update, but this certaintly can't be true, right?

Am I doing something wrong or is Google's data wrong?

Take this as an example

```
                  new cl. old cl.  new impr.   old impr.   new ctr   old ctr     new pos   old pos
[my search query]   0      3         0         622         0%         0.48%       0        5.86
```

So, you can see that the impressions dropped from 622 to 0 (!!!) and the crazy thing is: the position is showing a drop from 5.86 to 0 - and I don't get what that means. Does it mean the page is removed or blocked? If so, why can I see still see it if I search for it?

And like this, I have hundreds.

```
                new cl. old cl.  new impr.   old impr.   new ctr   old ctr     new pos   old pos
[my search query]   0   3          0           478         0%        0.63%       0         4.83                                                                 
[my search query]   0   3          0           420         0%        0.71%       0         6.2
```

Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: Google filters out some queries for privacy reasons. Maybe they started to get filtered out of the reports. If you look at a query over time, is it a sudden or gradual change in impressions. Did average position change?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know they did that. Average position for what? In general or a specific query you mean?

Comment: for a single query. Data like average position has little value unless looking at a single query.

Comment: Many potential reasons as you probably understand. This could be an algorithmic demotion, the reason you still see the keywords ranking when you search for them is probably because your results are being personalized. Also check the general trend of each keyword. Are these keywords seasonal? Are they related to some trending topic? Perhaps no one is searching for them. And of course you can't rule out a data bug on google's end.